# python regex optional capture group

Tags: python, regex

I have the following problem matching the needed data from filenames like this:

```
miniseries.season 1.part 5.720p.avi
miniseries.part 5.720p.avi
miniseries.part VII.720p.avi     # episode or season expressed in Roman numerals
```

The "season XX" chunk may or may not be present or may be written in short form, like "s 1" or "seas 1"

In any case I would like to have 4 capture groups giving as output :

```
group1 : miniseries
group2 : 1 (or None)
group3 : 5
group4 : 720p.avi
```

So I've written a regex like this :

```
(^.*)\Ws[eason ]*(\d{1,2}|[ivxlcdm]{1,5})\Wp[art ]*(\d{1,2}|[ivxlcdm]{1,5})\W(.*$)
```

This only works when i have a fully specified filename, including the optional "season XX" string.
Is it possible to write a regex that returns "None" as group2 if "season" is not found ?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It is easy enough to make the season group optional:

```
(^.*?)(?:\Ws(?:eason )?(\d{1,2}|[ivxlcdm]{1,5}))?\Wp(?:art )?(\d{1,2}|[ivxlcdm]{1,5})\W(.*$)
```

using a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`) plus the 0 or 1 quantifier (`?`). I did have to make the first group non-greedy to prevent it from matching the `season` section of the name.

I also made the `eason` and `art` optional strings into non-capturing optional groups instead of character classes.

Result:

```
>>> import re
>>> p=re.compile(r'(^.*?)(?:\Ws(?:eason )?(\d{1,2}|[ivxlcdm]{1,5}))?\Wp(?:art )?(\d{1,2}|[ivxlcdm]{1,5})\W(.*$)', re.I)
>>> p.search('miniseries.season 1.part 5.720p.avi').groups()
('miniseries', '1', '5', '720p.avi')
>>> p.search('miniseries.part 5.720p.avi').groups()
('miniseries', None, '5', '720p.avi')
>>> p.search('miniseries.part VII.720p.avi').groups()
('miniseries', None, 'VII', '720p.avi')
```