# Regex groups in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regex to identify data of the format:
XX days, XX hours, XX minutes (expecting minimal structural changes due to white spaces, comma and plurals)
I wanted to see an effecient python way of using regex so that I can get numbers associated with days hours and minutes.

I tried the following:

```
matchingTime = "27 days, 21 hours, 23 minutes ago"
re.search('([0-9]{0,2}).*day.* ([0-9]+) .*hour.* ([0-9]+) .*minute.*',matchingTime)
```

For the above case it works fine and I get the values in group 1 2 3 respectively.

The issue is either of the field may not necessarily be present, say

```
matchingTime = "21 hours, 23 minutes ago"
```

for the above case it fails.

I do know I can get it done using trys and excepts, but I was hoping to find a concise and efficient way of doing it.

Any inputs will be really helpful. Would be glad to give any further clarifications to my query.

EDIT: `[0-9]{0,2}` for the days part, just trying a few ways to solve this.

Comment: Just put non-capturing parens then ? around the optional part `'(:?([0-9]{0,2}).*day.* )?([0-9]+) .*hour.* ([0-9]+) .*minute.*'`

Comment: You want to have optional groups have a look at [python regex optional capture group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474741/python-regex-optional-capture-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps use a regex like:

```
(?:(?P<days>[0-9]{0,2})\s*day[^, ]*,? *)?(?:(?P<hrs>[0-9]+)\s*hour[^, ]*,? *)?(?:(?P<min>[0-9]+)\s*minute[^, ]*,? *)?
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/kY5kX2)

I'm using `[^, ]*,? *` for the optional commas and spaces and not using `.*` just so there's not too much backtracking.

I also used named capture groups and wrapped the whole groups for each day/hour/minute into a non-capture group, after which I put a `?` to mark them as optional. Each group is fairly similar:

```
(?:                       # Start of non-capture group
    (?P<days>[0-9]{0,2})  # Numbers to capture
    \s*                   # Spaces if any
    day                   # Literal match
    [^, ]*,? *            # Anything until first comma and optional spaces
)?                        # Close of non-capture group and marking it as optional
```

Comment: parenthesis is unbalanced.

Comment: So do I access the result in group 1 2 3 ?

Comment: @AjayNair In a similar fashion to what you have, except you use the name of the capture as string. The match object with `.group('days')` for days, `.group('hrs')` for hours, etc