# Capturing salary from a string using capture groups (python, regex)

Tags: python, regex

My goal is to extract salary from a string and if this salary comes from collective agreement. I have come up with a following regex:

```
pattern = "([Kk]ollektivvertragliche[sn]|Kollektivvertrag|[Cc]ollective [Aa]greement|[Kk]ollektivvertr|KV) .* ([0-9]{1,4}[.,][0-9]{2,3}[,]*[0-9]*) .* ([0-9]{1,4}[.,][0-9]{2,3}[,]*[0-9]*)"
```

- `([Kk]ollektivvertragliche[sn]|Kollektivvertrag|[Cc]ollective [Aa]greement|[Kk]ollektivvertr|KV)` - first group, that captures if salary is defined according to collective agreement.
- `([0-9]{1,4}[.,][0-9]{2,3}[,]*[0-9]*)` - is a salary of the form xx.yyy,zz/xx.yyy,zz/x.yyy/xxx (for example 21.950,13/1.859,20/1.700/700 $)
- `.+` between collective agreement and salary matches any character.

I have tested and it looks like it works well if all groups are available:

```
t = 'Entlohnung nach Caritas Kollektivvertrag : __ [lineBreak] Mindestgehalt in Gehaltsstufe 1 - Verwendungsgruppe VI , dzt. EUR 1.849,90 bis 1.900,32 '
r = re.search(pattern,t)
r.groups()
```

But if some of the groups(for example collective agreement or salary) is missed, it doesn't work.

```
string examples:
#t = 'EUR 35.362,00 Jahresbrutto'
#t = '2.800 brutto/Monat'
#t = 'laut Kollektivvertrag beträgt € 1.597,72 brutto pro Monat auf Basis Vollzeitbeschäftigung.'
#t = 'KV-Mindestgehalt von monatlich € 1.671,00'
#t = 'kollektivvertragliches Mindestgehalt von € 2.026,88 brutto pro Monat'
#t = 'Bruttojahreseinkommen ab € 50.000,'
#t = 'ein KV-Mindestlohn von EUR 1.277,00 brutto pro Monat'
#t = 'beträgt jedoch mindestens € 25.480'
#t = 'Gehalt lt. BAGS-KV €\xa02.100,78 brutto'
#t = 'kollektivvertraglicher Mindestgehalt EUR 33.000 Brutto/Jahr'
#t = '\nLohn/Gehalt ab EUR 2500,00 brutto monatlich,'
#t = 'KV IT __EUR 2.302'
#t = '25 Wochenstunden EUR [lineBreak] 1.641,91 bis EUR 1.859,21 brutto'
#t = 'Entlohnung nach Caritas Kollektivvertrag: __ [lineBreak] Mindestgehalt in Gehaltsstufe 1 - Verwendungsgruppe VI , dzt. EUR 1.849,90'
#t = 'The position is remunerated according to the Kollektivvertrag for Austrian Universities, i.e., the salary amounts to at least 38.230EUR/year before taxes'
#t = 'Erfahrung bieten wir ein Bruttojahresgehalt ab EUR 36.400.'
```

I have tried to impleemnt optional groups with a help of `?` and `?:` (like in this post [python regex optional capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474741/python-regex-optional-capture-group)), but it didn't work either.

**Desired output:** (group_1_result,group_2_result,group_3_result).

If some of the group is missed: instead of "group_n_result" I would like to have `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if `#t = '` is part of the string that you want in your return values, but using 3 capture groups where the first 2 are optional:

```
^.*?(?:\b([Kk]ollektivvertragliche[sn]|Kollektivvertrag|[Cc]ollective [Aa]greement|[Kk]ollektivvertr|KV)\b(.*?))?([0-9]{1,4}([.,])\d{2,3}(?:(?!\4)[.,]\d+)?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bl4TPm/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"^.*?(?:\b([Kk]ollektivvertragliche[sn]|Kollektivvertrag|[Cc]ollective [Aa]greement|[Kk]ollektivvertr|KV)\b(.*?))?([0-9]{1,4}([.,])\d{2,3}(?:(?!\4)[.,]\d+)?)"
s = ("#t = 'EUR 35.362,00 Jahresbrutto'\n"
     "#t = '2.800 brutto/Monat'\n"
     "#t = 'laut Kollektivvertrag beträgt € 1.597,72 brutto pro Monat auf Basis Vollzeitbeschäftigung.'\n"
     "#t = 'KV-Mindestgehalt von monatlich € 1.671,00'\n"
     "#t = 'kollektivvertragliches Mindestgehalt von € 2.026,88 brutto pro Monat'\n"
     "#t = 'Bruttojahreseinkommen ab € 50.000,'\n"
     "#t = 'ein KV-Mindestlohn von EUR 1.277,00 brutto pro Monat'\n"
     "#t = 'beträgt jedoch mindestens € 25.480'\n"
     "#t = 'Gehalt lt. BAGS-KV €\\xa02.100,78 brutto'\n"
     "#t = 'kollektivvertraglicher Mindestgehalt EUR 33.000 Brutto/Jahr'\n"
     "#t = '\\nLohn/Gehalt ab EUR 2500,00 brutto monatlich,'\n"
     "#t = 'KV IT __EUR 2.302'\n"
     "#t = '25 Wochenstunden EUR [lineBreak] 1.641,91 bis EUR 1.859,21 brutto'\n"
     "#t = 'Entlohnung nach Caritas Kollektivvertrag: __ [lineBreak] Mindestgehalt in Gehaltsstufe 1 - Verwendungsgruppe VI , dzt. EUR 1.849,90'\n"
     "#t = 'The position is remunerated according to the Kollektivvertrag for Austrian Universities, i.e., the salary amounts to at least 38.230EUR/year before taxes'\n"
     "#t = 'Erfahrung bieten wir ein Bruttojahresgehalt ab EUR 36.400.")
matches = re.finditer(pattern, s, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, m in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print((m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3)))
```

Output

```
(None, None, '35.362,00')
(None, None, '2.800')
('Kollektivvertrag', ' beträgt € ', '1.597,72')
('KV', '-Mindestgehalt von monatlich € ', '1.671,00')
('kollektivvertragliches', ' Mindestgehalt von € ', '2.026,88')
(None, None, '50.000')
('KV', '-Mindestlohn von EUR ', '1.277,00')
(None, None, '25.480')
('KV', ' €\\xa', '02.100,78')
(None, None, '33.000')
(None, None, '2500,00')
('KV', ' IT __EUR ', '2.302')
(None, None, '1.641,91')
('Kollektivvertrag', ': __ [lineBreak] Mindestgehalt in Gehaltsstufe 1 - Verwendungsgruppe VI , dzt. EUR ', '1.849,90')
('Kollektivvertrag', ' for Austrian Universities, i.e., the salary amounts to at least ', '38.230')
(None, None, '36.400')
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems capturing several groups matching the same pattern requires finditer.
The best I could achieve is this (with some tweaking you should be able to fit it to your needs):

```
import re

pattern1 = re.compile("([Kk]ollektivvertragliche[snr]|Kollektivvertrag|[Cc]ollective [Aa]greement|[Kk]ollektivvertr|KV)")
pattern2 = re.compile("([0-9]{1,4}.[0-9]{2,3}[,[0-9]+]*)")


t = ''''Entlohnung nach Caritas Kollektivvertrag : __ [lineBreak] Mindestgehalt in Gehaltsstufe 1 - Verwendungsgruppe VI , dzt. EUR 1.849,90 bis 1.900,32 '
#t = 'EUR 35.362,00 Jahresbrutto'
#t = '2.800 brutto/Monat'
#t = 'laut Kollektivvertrag beträgt € 1.597,72 brutto pro Monat auf Basis Vollzeitbeschäftigung.'
#t = 'KV-Mindestgehalt von monatlich € 1.671,00'
#t = 'kollektivvertragliches Mindestgehalt von € 2.026,88 brutto pro Monat'
#t = 'Bruttojahreseinkommen ab € 50.000,'
#t = 'ein KV-Mindestlohn von EUR 1.277,00 brutto pro Monat'
#t = 'beträgt jedoch mindestens € 25.480'
#t = 'Gehalt lt. BAGS-KV €\xa02.100,78 brutto'
#t = 'kollektivvertraglicher Mindestgehalt EUR 33.000 Brutto/Jahr'
#t = '\nLohn/Gehalt ab EUR 2500,00 brutto monatlich,'
#t = 'KV IT __EUR 2.302'
#t = '25 Wochenstunden EUR [lineBreak] 1.641,91 bis EUR 1.859,21 brutto'
#t = 'Entlohnung nach Caritas Kollektivvertrag: __ [lineBreak] Mindestgehalt in Gehaltsstufe 1 - Verwendungsgruppe VI , dzt. EUR 1.849,90'
#t = 'The position is remunerated according to the Kollektivvertrag for Austrian Universities, i.e., the salary amounts to at least 38.230EUR/year before taxes'
#t = 'Erfahrung bieten wir ein Bruttojahresgehalt ab EUR 36.400.'
'''
for line in t.splitlines():
    found = []
    r = re.search(pattern1,line)
    found.append(r[0] if r else r)
    
    for match in pattern2.finditer(line):
        found.append(match[0])

    print(found)

# ['Kollektivvertrag', '1.849,90', '1.900,32']
# [None, '35.362,00']
# [None, '2.800']
# ['Kollektivvertrag', '1.597,72']
# ['KV', '1.671,00']
# ['kollektivvertragliches', '2.026,88']
# [None, '50.000,']
# ['KV', '1.277,00']
# [None, '25.480']
# ['KV', '2.100,78']
# ['kollektivvertraglicher', '33.000']
# [None] (this one comes from \n ; such empty lines can be filtered out)
# [None, '2500,00']
# ['KV', '2.302']
# [None, '1.641,91', '1.859,21']
# ['Kollektivvertrag', '1.849,90']
# ['Kollektivvertrag', '38.230']
# [None, '36.400']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I also got it by 2 separated patters. But I am curious if it's possible to do with one line regex pattern

Comment: I understand your request and spent some time too fiddling with optional capture groups, but it didn't work better for me. Let's hope someone more knowledgeable will be able to shed light on this.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I upvoted your answer.